# Application crash on addOperation ( OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32 )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsoperationqueue

any one have any idea why application crash on this place
In code I am doing something like this

```
RequestOperation* requestOperation = [[[RequestOperation alloc]initWithItem:item delegate:self] autorelease]; 
[operationQueue addOperation:requestOperation];
```

Error Code

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGBUS
Exception Codes: BUS_ADRALN at 0x7c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x000053e4 OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32 + 0
1   Foundation                          0x00023235 ____addOperations_block_invoke_1 + 37
2   Foundation                          0x00022d91 __addOperations + 229
3   Foundation                          0x00022cab -[NSOperationQueue addOperation:] + 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BUS_ADRALN means that there is an address alignment problem.

I would check if the NSOperation object that is passed to [NSOperationQueue addOperation:] is valid.

Comment: Also, make sure that your NSOperationQueue isn't autoreleased or released soon after this.  I occasionally see people do this, which might lead to the above error.